# Getting JSON response as part of Rest call in Java

Tags: java, json, rest

I am trying to make Rest service call in Java. I am new to web and Rest service. I have Rest service which returns JSON as response. I have the following code but I think it's incomplete because I don't know how to process output using JSON.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            
            URL url = new URL("http://example.com:7000/test/db-api/processor"); 
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            connection.setDoOutput(true); 
            connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
            connection.setRequestMethod("PUT"); 
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream(); 
           //how do I get json object and print it as string
            os.flush(); 

            connection.getResponseCode(); 
            connection.disconnect(); 
        } catch(Exception e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(e); 
        } 

    }
```

I am new to Rest services and JSON.

Comment: If you are using Spring, it makes your life easy. It will perform a HTTP request, convert the HTTP response into an object type of your choice, and returns that object. https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a `PUT` request you're missing a few things here:

```
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(input.getBytes()); // The input you need to pass to the webservice
os.flush();
...
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream()))); // Getting the response from the webservice

String output;
System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output); // Instead of this, you could append all your response to a StringBuffer and use `toString()` to get the entire JSON response as a String.
    // This string json response can be parsed using any json library. Eg. GSON from Google.
}
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/) to have a more clear idea on hitting webservices.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is mostly correct, but there is mistake about `OutputStream`.
As R.J said `OutputStream` is needed to pass **request** body to the server.
If your rest service doesn't required any body you don't need to use this one.

For reading the server **response** you need use `InputStream`(R.J also show you example) like that:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[512];
    int read = -1;
    while ((read = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buf, 0, read);
    }
    System.out.println(new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
}
```

This way is good if you don't want to depends on third-part libraries. So I recommend you to take a look on [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) - very nice library with huge amount of very useful feature.

```
    Client client = JerseyClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
    Response response = client.target("http://host:port").
            path("test").path("db-api").path("processor").path("packages").
            request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).buildGet().invoke();
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Content-Type is application/json, you could directly cast the response to a JSON object for example

```
JSONObject recvObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
JsonKey jsonkey = objectMapper.readValue(new URL("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two"), JsonKey.class);
System.out.println("jsonkey.getOne() : "+jsonkey.getOne())
```